# Problem Using libcurl and SCons C++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, scons

My question is very similar to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351877/link-libcurl-library-using-scons

I have a C++ program I have to compile using SCons, and I'm trying to use libcurl to send post messages to a server. I've linked the libraries with this:

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "curl/types.h"
#include "curl/easy.h"
```

The issue comes up around here (code taken off the main website):

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
static const char buf[] = "Expect:";
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:
    undefined reference to `curl_global_init'

I've been stuck on this for a week now, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a link error, and it's happening because you probably didn't told the linker to link your application with **libcurl**, or you didn't specify the right directory for it to find it.

Check the section [Linking with Libraries](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.1.0.alpha.20101125/HTML/scons-user/x667.html) on the docs.

**EDIT:**

On a small test I did, the **SConstruct** looks like this:

```
Program('mycurl.c', LIBS='curl', 
                    LIBPATH=['/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib'])
```

And compiling with `scons -Q` succeeds and prints:

```
gcc -o mycurl.o -c mycurl.c
gcc -o mycurl mycurl.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl
```

which is exactly what you would do manually.

Comment: I understand how to do this in gcc/g++, but how would this work with scons?

Comment: I added a valid *scons* example for you @Bob.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my main problem is having to modify a fairly large and complex SConstruct file, but the documentation and examples will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

That is a linker error, nothing to do with compilation. Are you linking against the curl libraries?

Comment: I'm not sure how to link libraries with scons...  should I post the entire SConstruct file here?

Comment: Well, I have to ask why you are using scons then? As far as getting an answer out of me, posting the file would be useless, as I wouldn't touch scons with a bargepole.

Comment: I wish I didn't have to, but my program uses the CLAM Audio framework, which heavily uses scons. Switching to g++ would be an even bigger headache

Answer (score 0):

I've never used scons myself, but I found this link with a short tutorial on linking in libraries with scons.

http://www.scons.org/doc/0.97/HTML/scons-user/x628.html

I hope this helps.